# Java: How to extract substring between two characters from a string?

Tags: java, regex

I am relatively new to Java and I need some help to extract multiple substrings from a string. An example of a string is as given below:

```
String = "How/WRB can/MD I/PRP find/VB a/DT list/NN of/IN celebrities/NNS '/POS real/JJ names/NNS ?/."
```

Desired result: `WRB MD PRP VB DT NN IN NNS POS JJ NNS`

I have a text file with possibly thousands of similar POS-tagged lines that I need to extract the POS tags from and do some calculation based on the POS tags.

I have tried using tokenizer but didn't really get the result I wanted. I even tried using `split()` and saving to arrays because I need to store it and use it later and that still didn't work.

Lastly, I tried using Pattern Matcher and I am having problems with the regex as it return the word with the forward slash.

```
Regex: [\/](.*?)\s\b
Result: /WRB /MD ....
```

If there's a better way to do this, please let me know or if anyone can help me figure out what's wrong with my regex.

Comment: use `split()` function!! Have you Googled enough?

Comment: your regex seems fine, are your sure you are retrieving the correct group from the matcher? It looks like you print the group 0 and you would need the group 1 (containing what is inside the parenthesis)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
String string = "How/WRB can/MD I/PRP find/VB a/DT list/NN of/IN celebrities/NNS '/POS real/JJ names/NNS ?/.";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("[^/]+/([^ ]+ ?)", "$1"));
```

Prints: `WRB MD PRP VB DT NN IN NNS POS JJ NNS .`

Comment: OMG it worked perfectly! To think I've actually spent days trying to solve this problem. I didn't think the solution would be so simple. You guys are the best! I really didn't expect an answer so soon. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

If you still wanted to use pattern matching, look at [positive lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It will allow you to match a word that begins with a slash, but not actually match the slash itself.

An example would be something like this:

```
(?<=/).+?(?= |$)
```

Matches anything that starts with a slash, and is followed by a space OR the end of the string

Here is a working example written in Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class SO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "How/WRB can/MD I/PRP find/VB a/DT list/NN of/IN celebrities/NNS '/POS real/JJ names/NNS ?/.";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=/).+?(?= |$)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        // Loop through and find all matches and store them into the List
        while(matcher.find()) { 
            list.add(matcher.group()); 
        }

        // Print out the contents of this List
        for(String match : list) { 
            System.out.println(match); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Amandeep - Actually. I've struggled with this for a few weeks before deciding to post on here. I am normally to shy to ask for help.

Comment: @Cryssie u shud read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and post frankly.

Comment: @Amandeep - well I don't want to be a bother to anyone if I can sort it out myself.

Comment: @Cryssie it's alright to ask questions on here, and obviously you tried a lot of things which is great! I've updated my answer with a working example written in Java. Regular expressions are a little tricky but powerful when used correctly. Best of luck with whatever you are working on!

Comment: @Trevor - To be honest, it's rather embarrassing considering the amount of work and time I spent trying to figure this out compared with the solution which seems so simple...I am enjoying learning Java a bit more now.

Answer (score 2):

```
String string = "How/WRB can/MD I/PRP find/VB a/DT list/NN of/IN celebrities/NNS '/POS real/JJ names/NNS ?/.";

string = string .replaceAll("\\S+/", "").replace(".", "");  

System.out.println(string );
```

Comment: +1 you need to escape dot `\\.`, use `str.replaceAll("\\S+/", "").replaceAll("\\.", "");`

Answer (score 0):

What about `str = str.repalceAll("\\S+/", "")`? It will replace remove non-whitespace characters followed by slash.